# DTXDssClient not allowing to enter command to process dsym file

Tags: ios, undefined-symbol, dynatrace, dsym

I want to upload dsym file to dynatrace, i followed https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/platform-modules/digital-experience/mobile-applications/analyze-and-use/upload-and-manage-symbol-files  link and downloaded DTXDssClient but it is not allowing to enter [image]anything

i followed https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/platform-modules/digital-experience/mobile-applications/analyze-and-use/upload-and-manage-symbol-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For zsh shell need to go to the directory where the DTXDssClient and then for the command need to use "./DTXDssClient" as below

./DTXDssClient -decode symbolsfile=/Users/name/Downloads/DynatraceDSYM/Archive.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).